# Cannot implicitly convert type IEnumerable<List<Metric>>' to 'IEnumerable<Metric>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary, extension-methods

I am new to c# advanced programming, so a lot of it is very new for me to grasp.

I am trying to extend my custom Dictionary object that has a custom class and a list of custom class for key-value pair.

In this static class I am extending a partial match feature for a partial key for my dictionary that should return a `List<T>` instead of just one `T`.

```
public static class GADictionaryExtention
{
    internal static List<T> PartialMatch<T>(this Dictionary<KeyDimensions, T> dictionary, 
                                            KeyDimensions partialKey)
    {
        IEnumerable<KeyDimensions> fullMatchingKeys = null;
        fullMatchingKeys = dictionary.Keys.Where(currentKey => currentKey.Contains(partialKey));
        List<T> returnedValues = new List<T>();

        foreach (KeyDimensions currentKey in fullMatchingKeys)
        {
            returnedValues.Add(dictionary[currentKey]);
        }

        return returnedValues;
    }
}
```

In my invocation code I am trying to access all the `List<T>` results by the following code.

```
List<List<Metric>> m1 = DataDictionary.PartialMatch(kd);
```

but I am getting the following error.

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<Metric>>'
to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Metric>'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: What is the declaration of the DataDictionary type? It seems somewhere you mistakenly used a List<T> instead of List<List<T>>.

Comment: This is the declaration for DataDictionary

        Dictionary<KeyDimensions, List<Metric>> DataDictionary = new Dictionary<KeyDimensions, List<Metric>>();

Comment: @spyronum Your code looks fine. I'm sure the error is from somewhere else. Try re-compiling the whole thing.

Comment: "An explicit conversion exists": I've always found this error message very misleading, because it's just plain wrong...

Comment: @Spyronum, the code as you posted does not throw this exception. Please double-check, if your code and type declarations really are exactly as posted here.

Comment: WOW!!!
@nawfal i guess experience counts for a lot of it. I just recompiled my entire project and no more error.
Thanks a lot guys for your time here. I appreciate the prompt replies you all made here.

help appreciated +elgonzo/nawfal/sarwar026

Answer (score 1):

Your invocation call should be like this:

```
List<Metric> m1 = DataDictionary.PartialMatch(kd);
```

Since you are returning `List<T>` from the extension method.

**Update:**
According to your comment, `T = List<Metric>`, I think, you should cast the result like below:

```
List<List<Metric>> m1 = (List<List<Metric>>)DataDictionary.PartialMatch(kd);
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion there.
The T is a custom type of class Metric
In the code
T = List<Metric>
So what i get from the extension class is List<List<Metric>> or supposed to get but i am getting the error now.

Comment: What does the declaration of the type used for DataDictionary look like? Please post it.

Comment: @Sarwar026: The cast would be redundant, look at the return type of the extension method.

Comment: @elgonzo please refer to my reply to your comment. I have posted the declaration there.

+sarwar026 I tried to do what you suggested but still am getting the error. more over i tried to place the method call without any assignment and that line was flagged with the same error tag, from that I suspect the error is being caused inside my extended method. not at the return value or assignment.

Any other suggestions?